# Do I need Javascript MVC in Hybrid App?

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, hybrid-mobile-app, jqmobi, appframework

I am currently developing an application for Android using AppFramework + Intel XDK (AppMobi).
As this application will involves a lot of Javascript codes, some reading on the internet suggest to use MVC approach (Backbone JS, Intel MVC, etc).

Regarding to performance, people that I know told me that using MVC will decrease the application performance.

So, can you all give me suggestion, should I use MVC or keep the traditional way?
If MVC is needed, which MVCs framework that performs better with Intel AppFramework (JqMobi)?

Thanks

Comment: MVC is quite traditional, too... though nobody can tell you which is the better approach, as we don't know what your app will be. If it is quite sizeable, the benefit of MVC is that it keeps things organized. There's a clear separation of concern: A controller shouldn't contain a lot of business logic, nor should it render any output. Those are the tasks of the model _layer_ and the view scripts respectively. Basically the tradeoff is: performace <=> maintainability